# Verification Process of Paypal transactions

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated PayPal SDK in my android app and done transaction successfully in sandbox environment.Now the second step mentioned in docs  is verification . I tried to hit rest Api with payment id in browser but  it dint give me any response . So please tell me the proper way of verification .Here is the [link](http://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) I have followed

Also I have got client secret key but dont know where to use it . Will it be needed in verification process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need your ClientID and Secret to generate an Access Token that will then be used in subsequent Payment Lookup call. More information on creating the Access Token can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) under step 2 of Getting an Access Token.  That Access Token is then used in the payment lookup API call that you see on the Verify Mobile Payment link you provided in your question. More information/samples of a RESTful Payment Lookup call can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource) as well.